# Weird icomoon / ie 9 & 10 / :before / apache DNS issue

Tags: css, apache, internet-explorer, drupal, font-face

I have a really weird problem that I am not sure how to go about solving.  I'm using an @font-face icon font on my site.  This works fine in most places except when I go to the site with internet explorer 9 or 10 and don't use the www. prefix.  The site works fine in internet explorer 8, and it also works fine if you use the www. prefix.  Not only that but the site works fine in another almost identical site.  Not sure how to go about fixing this.  I think it is a DNS or apache issue (something to do maybe with how the files were set up), but I could use any suggestions.

Sites it does not work (ie 9 & 10 only):

```
http://itascainternational.com
```

Sites the icon font does work:

```
http://www.itascainternational.com
http://itascacg.com
http://www.itascacg.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you access your site using **www**, the font works.
One option, not recommended, is to redirect itascainternational.com www.itascainternational.com. It's a good practice to prevent duplicate content. But It not solves the problem.

It's probable that you have problems with **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**
. You have to add it in your apache config.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mydomain.com"
  </IfModule>  
</FilesMatch>
```

Regards.